PNG image is partially corrupt when loading into word document with wand.image.Image
I am trying to create a Python script that takes multiple one-page SVG files, converting them to a PNG file, and then combining them into one word document. But when inspecting the word document the images are partially corrupt with black ink covering more than half of the image.
The image inside the word document looks like this (shouldn't be covered in black ink);

Python code
from docx import Document
from wand.image import Image
from io import BytesIO

def create_word_document(input_files: list[str], output_docx: str):
    doc = Document()
    for svg_file in input_files:
        with Image(filename=svg_file, format='svg') as img:
            width, height = 600, 800  
            img.resize(width, height)

            with img.convert('png') as converted:
                png_bytes = converted.make_blob('png')
                
        doc.add_picture(BytesIO(png_bytes))
    doc.save(output_docx)


It is possible that the black overlay on the svg is in fact a shape filled with the default black fill

@enxaneta is there a way to remove the shape

You delete it. It's probably the last element of the svg. Maybe a  or a . Alternatively you can add fill="none" to the shape.  Impossible to tell more without seeing the code.

It only appears after it has been converted to a png, the black fill doesn't show when viewing the SVG inside a browser

@enxaneta its from this svg; https://musescore.com/static/musescore/scoredata/g/0740ea9c3594bed351dceb81db76db5e1f83fe18/score_0.svg?no-cache=1598032114
